# AVAudioPayer aiff file to mp3 or wma

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, mp3, avaudiorecorder

I am recording audio using AVAudioRecorder. Right now, it's making the file in .aiff, how can i make it in mp3 or wma?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that mp3 encoding is not supported on iPhone. Oh well.

Answer (score -2):

When you initialize the audio recorder with the following method

```
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url settings:(NSDictionary *)settings error:(NSError **)outError
```

you specify the setting, which is a dictionary.

You can specify the format using the key "AVFormatIDKey" described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationAudioSettings_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009937)

For different formats available, go to the "Core Audio Data types" in the "Constants" section of this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CoreAudioDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004488)

To make long story short, you might end up doing something like this.

```
NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEGLayer3] forKey:AVFormatIDKey]; // for mp3
```

And then specify this recordSetting in the init method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So if I want to get it in mp4 or wma, which format should I use? Thanks again

Comment: Actually, mp3 encoding is not supported on iOS. The list you provided is a bit misleading, not everything there is supported. Thanks for the help though.